# Scrapy startproject not working with git-bash

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, anaconda, git-bash

I'm working on win7 on a system with git-bash. I've installed Miniconda and loaded scrapy using:

```
conda install -c scrapinghub scrapy
```

I've set the environmental variables to contain:

```
C:\Miniconda2;C:\Miniconda2\Scripts
```

Now within the scrapy vitualenv, when I do :

```
(scrapy)
$ scrapy startproject scrapytest    
sh: scrapy: command not found
```

How do I use the scrapy command line tool here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how git-bash has effect on this, but installing scrapy [registers one entry point, a console script](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/setup.py#L23), calling `scrapy.cmdline:execute`. See [this page](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) for more info on entry points.

You can invoke the same using the python interpreter with `-m` like this:

```
python -m scrapy.cmdline startproject scrapytest
```

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be a problem with using the anaconda install command above. I created a new virtualenv using python 2.7.11 and installed scrapy using pip and it worked. Part of the problem earlier may have been that pip was not updated to the latest version , so do this first. here is a list of packages I ended up installing in my virtual env:

```
$ pip list
attrs (15.2.0)
backports-abc (0.4)
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size (1.0.0)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.5.0.1)
certifi (2016.2.28)
cffi (1.6.0)
configparser (3.5.0)
cryptography (1.3.2)
cssselect (0.9.1)
decorator (4.0.9)
entrypoints (0.2.2)
enum34 (1.1.6)
functools32 (3.2.3.post2)
idna (2.1)
ipaddress (1.0.16)
ipykernel (4.3.1)
ipython (4.2.0)
ipython-genutils (0.1.0)
ipywidgets (5.1.4)
Jinja2 (2.8)
jsonschema (2.5.1)
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (4.2.2)
jupyter-console (4.1.1)
jupyter-core (4.1.0)
lxml (3.6.0)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
mistune (0.7.2)
nbconvert (4.2.0)
nbformat (4.0.1)
notebook (4.2.0)
parsel (1.0.2)
pathlib2 (2.1.0)
pickleshare (0.7.2)
pip (8.1.2)
psycopg2 (2.6.1)
ptyprocess (0.5.1)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pyasn1-modules (0.0.8)
pycparser (2.14)
PyDispatcher (2.0.5)
Pygments (2.1.3)
pyOpenSSL (16.0.0)
pyreadline (2.1)
pywin32 (220)
pyzmq (15.2.0)
qtconsole (4.2.1)
queuelib (1.4.2)
Scrapy (1.1.0)
service-identity (16.0.0)
setuptools (21.1.0)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
singledispatch (3.4.0.3)
six (1.10.0)
SQLAlchemy (1.0.13)
terminado (0.6)
tornado (4.3)
traitlets (4.2.1)
Twisted (16.2.0)
w3lib (1.14.2)
widgetsnbextension (1.2.2)
zope.interface (4.1.3)
```